# Canon EOS 1300D does not fire studio flash via sync cable on hot shoe adapter

Tags: canon, flash

I have a Canon EOS 1300D on which I have mounted a simple hot shoe adapter with sync port so I can connect it to my Jinbei Spark-II 300 studio flash.

Problem is the studio flash isn't firing. I have tried the hot shoe adapter in a NIKON D200 -> works, also in an older Olympus E-520 camera -> works.

Anyone any idea why it wouldn't work on the Canon EOS 1300D? Flash is enabled on the camera. I have tried both with Live view enabled and disabled.

Comment: Can you specify the exact hot shoe adapter you are using?

Comment: What flash control menu options are selected on your 1300D menu?

Comment: Hi, the hot shoe adapter is one from falcon eyes [link](http://www.camerashop.be/product/209820/falcon-eyes-hotshoe-hs-25b-x-contact.html?ref=265874&label=22727-AGI-32625431941-ASI-112680566910-209820&gclid=CNaG9uHX_tACFUa3GwodJ3oMLQ)

Comment: On the 1300D (T6 in USA), all I can set is flash firing "enabled" and built in flash function settings (but they are not available when the hot shoe is in, all i can do then is enable the flash).

Comment: Are you sure the adapter is properly seated on the hotshoe (pushed all the way in, so the sync pin on the foot meets the big contact in the center of the camera's hotshoe)?

Comment: It's pushed onto the fitting as far as it goes. I do find, compared to the other two camera's, that the fitting is a bit on the loose side. I've trie pushing down on it, to see if maybe the contact is bad or something, but to no avail. What i have also tried is using a volt meter, to see if anything goes through the cable. When i press the shutter of the camera, the volt spikes to about 11 volts on the other end of the cable (connector that needs to go in flash unit), so it looks like something is being sent through, but maybe not enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a faulty connection on the adapter. Bought a different one which fit way better on the camera. Works like a charm. Thanks for all the help though!